# Fragment Replace is causing problems yet again

Tags: android, android-fragments

My activity XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentFrame1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have an attachView method that invokes from onCreate of the activity

```
@Override
protected void attachView() {
    // Get the fragment from dagger
    getFragmentManager().
            beginTransaction().
            setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_up, 0, 0, R.animator.slide_down).
            replace(R.id.contentFrame1, new MatchFragment2()).
            addToBackStack("MatchFragment").
            commit();
    getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getFragmentManager().
                    beginTransaction().
                    setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_up, 0, 0, R.animator.slide_down).
                    replace(R.id.contentFrame1, new VictorFragment()).
                    addToBackStack("VictorFragment").
                    commit();
            getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
            getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount(); //this reads 2
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

When I press back from the VictorFragment , I am greeted with MatchFragment.
Shouldn't the VictorFragment be the lone existing fragment in the scenario and pressing back from it should exit the activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete your call to the `addToBackStack()` method.

When you call this on a `FragmentTransaction`, you're telling the system that you want it to "remember" the transaction and allow you to "undo" it by pressing the back button. So if you *don't* want the back button to take away the `VictorFragment` and re-show the `MatchFragment2`, then you should **not** call `addToBackStack()` on that transaction.